# Next.js with Swagger

Tags: javascript, swagger, next.js

Is there a way to have a swagger documentation for NEXT.js API routes?
I'm using Next.js for both front-end and back-end development and I want to have a swagger documentation for the APIs I develop with Next.js.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following project to bootstrap the integration between Next.js and Swagger

- https://github.com/jellydn/next-swagger-doc
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-swagger-doc
- [Demo](https://next-swagger-doc-demo.productsway.com/api-doc)

```
yarn add next-swagger-doc swagger-ui-react
```

```
import { GetStaticProps, InferGetStaticPropsType } from 'next';

import { createSwaggerSpec } from 'next-swagger-doc';
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-react';
import 'swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css';

const ApiDoc = ({ spec }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
  return <SwaggerUI spec={spec} />;
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ctx => {
  const spec: Record<string, any> = createSwaggerSpec({
    title: 'NextJS Swagger',
    version: '0.1.0',
  });
  return { props: { spec } };
};

export default ApiDoc;
```

The actual definition of a Next.js API route endpoint looks like this:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/hello:
 *   get:
 *     description: Returns the hello world
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: hello world
 */
const handler = (_req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    result: 'hello world',
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a little npm library that auto-generates Swagger docs from your NextJS project. No user input needed!

Still very Beta but hope it's useful.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-routes-docs

Just run

```sh
npx nextjs-routes-docs [dir]
```

Answer (score 3):

You got to have the swagger json files or specification for the APIS and can use libs such as [Swagger UI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) or [Redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc)

Using Redoc you can do a /doc/[slug].js and do dynamic fetching on the .json or yaml files for your documentation (or swagger ui)

This website: https://openapi.tools/ , has a lot of tools for React and OpenAPI in general that you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the following steps, if you have already annotated your `route.js` files with `JSDoc ie. @swagger` in NextJS 13.

**Step 1.**

Install dependencies

`npm i swagger-ui-react swagger-jsdocs`

**Step 2.**

Create a component file `src/components/swagger-doc.jsx` to render the swagger documentation using `swagger-ui-react`

```
'use client';

// Import Modules
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Import Components
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-react';

// Import Miscs
import 'swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css';

const SwaggerDoc = ({ spec }) => (
  <SwaggerUI spec={spec} />
);

SwaggerDoc.propTypes = {
  /**
   * OpenApi specifications
   */
  spec: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object]).isRequired,
};

export default SwaggerDoc;
```

**Step 3.**

Create a configuration file `src/configs.js` having `swagger-jsdocs` options

```
const CONFIG = {
  jsDocs: {
    apis: ['**/api/v1/**/route.js'],
    swaggerDefinition: {
      info: {
        title: 'Some Service',
        version: '0.0.1',
        description: 'This is an API doc for Some Service.',
      },
    },
  },
};

export default CONFIG;
```

**Step 4.**

Create a `/docs` route by creating `src/app/docs/page.jsx`

```
// Import Modules
import swaggerJsdoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';

// Import Components
import SwaggerDoc from '../../components/swagger-doc';

// Import Miscs
import CONFIG from '../../configs';

const getData = async () => {
  const spec = swaggerJsdoc(CONFIG.jsDocs);

  return spec;
};

const Docs = async () => {
  const data = await getData();

  return <SwaggerDoc spec={data} />;
};

export default Docs;
```

**Note:**
You can see the detailed configurations of the dependencies here

[swagger-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc) [swagger-ui-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react)

Comment: Great job, there's no docs on using /app directory with this lib.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for autogenerating OpenAPI spec files from your API routes is to use Next REST Framework: https://github.com/blomqma/next-rest-framework